# GitHub Actions: productsign hangs

Tags: macos, github-actions, code-signing, fastlane, productsign

I am having an issue with GitHub Actions. When I call `productsign` the job just hangs. When searching the internet it seems that the job tries to ask the user for a password but I do not get any errors or feedback from the logs. The job just hangs for ever. When run on my own computer everything works as expected and the .pkg is signed.

My step in the workflow is as follows

```
  - name: Build & Sign Installer
    run: |
      export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
      export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
      (cd fastlane && ./decrypt_secret.sh)
      carthage update --use-xcframeworks --platform macOS
      bundle exec fastlane set_release_version
      bundle exec fastlane mac install_certificates
      bundle exec fastlane mac build_main_app
      bundle exec fastlane mac build_updater
      bundle exec fastlane mac build_installer
      (cd installer && productsign --sign <identity> app-1.0.0.pkg app-1.0.0-signed.pkg)
```

I have tried a lot of different solutions, but nothing works

1. `security import ${P12_FILE} -k ${KEYCHAIN_PATH} -P ${P12_PASSWORD} -A`
2. `security import ${P12_FILE} -k ${KEYCHAIN_PATH} -P ${P12_PASSWORD} -T /usr/bin/productsign`
3. Setting partition list using `security set-key-partition-list`
4. creating a new keychain / unlocking keychain
5. Switched to use the --sign param on `productbuild` (also hangs when --sign added)
6. Manually imported the certificate without `fastlane match` at all
7. I think any other solution found on google

Any ideas? Is this a bug in GitHub Actions?

Comment: What is `<identity>`? And why are you having opened bracket at the last line and not any closed bracket? Why you even have brackets, why not only `<command1> && <command2>`?

Comment: Identity is "Developer ID Installer: <companyname>, LLC (<teamid>)". Fixed the missing ) as it was a copy/paste error. Use of () should not have any impact as it issues a subcontext (as i remember it) and i wont have to cd back out again. But i can try without :o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, we finally figured it out. The solution is to create tmp keychain, set its as default and configure some attributes. This makes sure `codesign` and `productsign` can access it without being prompted for a password.

**Setup Tmp Keychain**

```
# default again user login keychain
security list-keychains -d user -s login.keychain

# Create temp keychain
security create-keychain -p "$MY_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" "$MY_KEYCHAIN"

# Append temp keychain to the user domain
security list-keychains -d user -s "$MY_KEYCHAIN" $(security list-keychains -d user | sed s/\"//g)

# Remove relock timeout
security set-keychain-settings "$MY_KEYCHAIN"

# Unlock keychain
security unlock-keychain -p "$MY_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" "$MY_KEYCHAIN"

# Add certificate to keychain
security import $CERT -k "$MY_KEYCHAIN" -P "$CERT_PASSWORD" -A -T "/usr/bin/codesign" -T "/usr/bin/productsign"

# Enable codesigning from a non user interactive shell
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:, -s -k $MY_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD -D "${IDENTITY_CERTIFICATE}" -t private $MY_KEYCHAIN
```

**Clean up Keychain**

```
# Delete temporary keychain
security delete-keychain "$MY_KEYCHAIN"

# default again user login keychain
security list-keychains -d user -s login.keychain
```

Comment: Hi @Rasmus Styrk, I'm looking for a way to sign a .pkg file using `productsign` as well through Github Actions. Do you have a workflow reference or a documentation suggestion regarding how to achieve this please? (it's not clear for me what I should configure in my repo to achieve the same result as yours).

Comment: @GuiFalourd did you find a solution?

Comment: I found one yes! I explained all the process with notarization as well in this repo: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/sign-and-notarize-gha

Comment: I also added this question and answer here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991268/how-to-sign-and-notarize-a-pkg-within-a-github-actions-macos-runner