# How to sign and notarize a PKG within a Github Actions macos runner

Tags: macos, certificate, github-actions, sign, notarize

#### Context

I'm building a Github Actions job to **build, sign and notarize** a PKG file.

I'm using an **Apple Id account** (the workflow needs username and password) as well as a **Developer Id Installer** certificate with private key (encrypted). Both are saved as secrets (base64) and will be converted in the workflow to a .p12 file, then added to keychain.

This job is part of a bigger workflow in a private repository, that generates first the files (using [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) from the software, and then export the PKG on a AWS S3 Bucket.

#### The implementation

```yaml
jobs:
  [...]

  pkg:
    needs: [...]
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download macos bin file
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: macos-bin-files
          path: dist/
      - name:
        run: | 
          ----- Create certificate files from secrets base64 -----
          echo ${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_ID_INSTALLER_CER }} | base64 --decode > certificate_installer.cer
          echo ${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_ID_INSTALLER_KEY }} | base64 --decode > certificate_installer.key

          ----- Create p12 file -----
          openssl pkcs12 -export -name zup -in certificate_installer.cer -inkey certificate_installer.key -passin pass:${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }} -out certificate_installer.p12 -passout pass:${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}

          ----- Configure Keychain -----
          KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db
          security create-keychain -p "${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security unlock-keychain -p "${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}" $KEYCHAIN_PATH

          ----- Import certificates on Keychain -----
          security import certificate_installer.p12 -P "${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH

          ----- Generate PKG from files -----
          use a macos installer script (ref: https://github.com/KosalaHerath/macos-installer-builder/tree/master/macOS-x64)

          ----- Sign PKG file -----
          productsign --sign "${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_ID_INSTALLER_NAME }}" $INPUT_FILE_PATH $OUTPUT_FILE_PATH

          - name: "Notarize Release Build PKG"
            uses: devbotsxyz/xcode-notarize@v1 
            with:
              product-path: $PATH_TO_PKG
              appstore-connect-username: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME }}
              appstore-connect-password: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}
              primary-bundle-id: 'BUNDLE_ID'

          - name: "Staple Release Build"
            uses: devbotsxyz/xcode-staple@v1
            with:
              product-path: $PATH_TO_PKG

  [...]
```

#### Issue

I followed the Github Action official documentation for [installing an Apple certificate on macOS runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development) and this part is working as expected. I can add the certificate to keychain and use it to sign the PKG file with the `productsign` command.

However, when I send the PKG to Apple for notarization, it returns me that error:

```
Error: Notarization status <invalid> - Package Invalid
Error: Notarization failed
```

#### What I tried

The PKG is working as expected when distributed (just need to be opened as admin as not notarized), so the problem doesn't seem related to the package implementation.

I tried to perform the notarization with command lines, following links from different sources:

- [Notarization Rejected for .pkg installer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123856)
- [How to notarize an MacOS command line tool created outside of XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64652704/how-to-notarize-an-macos-command-line-tool-created-outside-of-xcode)
- [Notarize a Command Line Tool](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/09/notarize-a-command-line-tool/)
- [How to notarize app at CI build?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107976)

However, even with those command lines (without using the notarize action), I couldn't notarize the PKG file.

#### Question

**What is wrong with my workflow, did I miss something before trying to notarize the package?**

*PS: I couldn't find any reference doing this on a Github Actions macos runner...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Solution

After setting the `devbotsxyz/xcode-notarize@v1` field `verbose:true`, I observed that Apple returns a link to a JSON explaining why the package is INVALID for notarization.

In this JSON, it was informed that all the files composing my PKG (there are many as I couldn't use `--onefile` with Pyinstaller in my context) were invalid **because they weren't signed and timestamped**.

After some researches, I found [this post on the Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/130855) and understood that **PKG files need to be signed INSIDE OUT**: First, you sign each file generated by Pyinstaller, then sign the PKG gathering all those files.

To do so, you can't use the `productsign` command (as it only work for .pkg, .zip and .dmg) but `codesign`.

However, `codesign` doesn't use a `Developer Id Installer certificate`, but a `Developer Id Application certificate`, so I had to add this new certificate to the workflow as well.

*Note that as my PKG would be composed of hundreds of files, I also needed [a bash script to use codesign to sign each one of them](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/4efc73f1a6014b791c0ef223a023520a).*

**My final workflow looks like this:**

```yaml
jobs:
  [...]

  pkg:
    needs: [...]
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download macos bin file
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: macos-bin-files
          path: dist/
      - name:
        run: | 
          ----- Create certificate files from secrets base64 -----
          echo ${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_ID_INSTALLER_CER }} | base64 --decode > certificate_installer.cer
          echo ${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_ID_INSTALLER_KEY }} | base64 --decode > certificate_installer.key
          echo ${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_ID_APPLICATION_CER }} | base64 --decode > certificate_application.cer
          echo ${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_ID_APPLICATION_KEY }} | base64 --decode > certificate_application.key

          ----- Create p12 file -----
          openssl pkcs12 -export -name zup -in certificate_installer.cer -inkey certificate_installer.key -passin pass:${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }} -out certificate_installer.p12 -passout pass:${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}
          openssl pkcs12 -export -name zup -in certificate_application.cer -inkey certificate_application.key -passin pass:${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }} -out certificate_application.p12 -passout pass:${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}

          ----- Configure Keychain -----
          KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db
          security create-keychain -p "${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security unlock-keychain -p "${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}" $KEYCHAIN_PATH

          ----- Import certificates on Keychain -----
          security import certificate_installer.p12 -P "${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security import certificate_application.p12 -P "${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH

          ----- Codesign files with script -----
          use a script to sign each file from the artifact (ref: https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/4efc73f1a6014b791c0ef223a023520a)

          ----- Generate PKG from codesigned files -----
          use a macos installer script (ref: https://github.com/KosalaHerath/macos-installer-builder/tree/master/macOS-x64)

          ----- Sign PKG file -----
          productsign --sign "${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_ID_INSTALLER_NAME }}" $INPUT_FILE_PATH $OUTPUT_FILE_PATH

          - name: Notarize Release Build PKG
            uses: lando/notarize-action@v2
            with:
              product-path: $PATH_TO_PKG
              appstore-connect-username: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME }}
              appstore-connect-password: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}
    appstore-connect-team-id: FY8GAUX283 # if using notarytool

          - name: "Staple Release Build"
            uses: devbotsxyz/xcode-staple@v1
            with:
              product-path: $PATH_TO_PKG

  [...]
```

EDIT: Notary tools have been updated on Apple. Previously the action below was used in the process but has been removed from the marketplace:

```
- name: "Notarize Release Build PKG"
  uses: devbotsxyz/xcode-notarize@v1 
  with:
   product-path: $PATH_TO_PKG
   appstore-connect-username: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME }}
   appstore-connect-password: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}
   primary-bundle-id: 'BUNDLE_ID'
```

Comment: Note, the `devbotsxyz/xcode-notarize` action was removed. Now the alternatives seems to be the https://github.com/lando/notarize-action

Answer (score 2):

I used the notarize action before, but it is no longer maintained, or even available. However, you can directly use the `xcrun` tools in your actions:

```
  - name: Notarize Disk Image
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'release' }}
    env:
      DMG_PATH: path/to/your/dmg
      AC_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.AC_USERNAME }}
      AC_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.AC_PASSWORD }}
    run: xcrun notarytool submit ${DMG_PATH} --wait --apple-id ${AC_USERNAME} --password ${AC_PASSWORD} --team-id '<your team ID>'

  - name: Staple Release Build
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'release' }}
    env:
      DMG_PATH: path/to/your/dmg
    run: xcrun stapler staple ${DMG_PATH}

  - name: Upload Release Assets
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'release' }}
    run: gh release upload ${{ github.ref }} ${DMG_PATH}
    env:
      DMG_PATH: path/to/your/dmg
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
```